Proof of discontinuous linear map on a Banach space without using infinite bases
A discontinuous linear map from a Banach space $X$ to a normed vector space $Y$ can be show to exist using a countable linearly-independent subset of a Hamel basis.
I was wondering if it is possible to give a (non-constructive) proof of the existence of such a map without using the notion of infinite bases at all — for example using the Baire category theorem.
By the closed graph theorem, it is sufficient to find a sequence $(x_n \in X)$ converging to $0$ and a linear map $T \colon X \to Y$ such that $Tx_n \rightarrow y \not= 0$.
My idea was to deduce the existence of such a sequence using the completeness of $X$ and Baire, but I haven't yet managed to progress.
Even if such a strategy is not viable in general, I would be interested if there was a special case of $X$ in which it worked.

But the existence of a Hamel basis is already non-constructive. So using a construction based on a Hamel basis should also be considered "non-constructive" in my opinion.

True - I have corrected the wording of the question!

The completness of $X$ is not essential. It suffices that the dimension of $X$ is infinite. Hence  theorems related to Baire category are not useful if we do not insist on completness of $X.$

Yes - although I am particularly interested in showing that such a map does exist on a Banach space - and wish to do so without using a Hamel basis.

I am not sure if the following counts. It is pretty similar to the construction with a Hamel basis, but does not use a Hamel basis.
Choose a linearly independent sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset X$ and let $V$ denote the span of $(x_n)$. We define a linear map $f_0 \colon V \to \mathbb R$ via $f_0(x_n) = n x_n$. With Hahn-Banach, $f_0$ can be extended (non-constructively) to a linear map $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$. Of course, $f$ is not continuous.

Thanks - that's a very clean solution - although I was ideally looking for something even more elementary. Perhaps it is just not possible!

What do you mean with "more elementary"? Not using any advanced theorems? At least, you have to invoke the axiom of choice in some way or another.

I want to avoid using either Hahn-Banach or Hamel bases, but understand that it may not be possible.
